# Automated Video Generation by Script (e.g. YML)

Tags: text-to-video

I need to to generate "Howto" videos to explain various aspects of software releases. They should enhance / replace manuals.

There are many video generation services out there today. But every service requires manual operations or at least finishing.

I'm looking for a pure script driven video generation - without manual intervention.

Such a script could be a yml file. Here is an idea of how this could look like:

```
output:
  - filename: howto1.mov
  - format: mov
  - resolution: 600x400px

content:
  scenes:
    scene1:
      type: scene
      visual:
        - name: intro
        - heading: "Howto: Copying Character"
        - subtitle: "Explaining Software #1 Version 1.2.3 of Corp xxx"
      audio:
        audio1:
          - type: speaker
          - chachter: carl
          - text: "Hi, this is tom, your software guide. Let me show you how to copy characters"
          - apprearance: top-left
          - style: circle
          - size: 200x200px
        audio2:
          - type: background-music
          - beethoven.mp3
          - volume: 1
      background:
        - image: landscape.png
    scene2:
      type: scene
      visual:
        - name: slide1
        - heading: "Preparation: Start Editor"
    ...
```

What is the best was to proceed here? Writing such a generator, combining existing ones or are there already projects doing similar tasks (didn't find any)?

Comment: WeSee Yes, there is a GenAI Meta. You can find the link in the Help dropdown, the Stack Exchange, pro tip: all the child metas are hosted in meta.stackexhange.com, just prepend the site name: https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com. P.S. GenAI Meta was very quiet lately.